# How to create a diagonal matrix from column with diagonal values using a dynamic array function

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with a column with values I would like to use as a diagonal matrix for some matrix multiplication. I would like to achieve this without actually displaying the diagonal matrix, but only displaying the result of some matrix operation on the diagonal matrix as shown in the example in the picture. For this purpose I would like a dynamic array formula to create the diagonal matrix from which the result can be fed into for example MMULT-function without displaying the diagonal matrix. Any ideas of how this can be done?

[Column with diagonal values, and diagonal matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFKvG.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can try-

```
=LET(x,IF(MUNIT(ROWS(B3:B5))=1,B3:B5,0),MMULT(x,x))
```

Another way with `MAKEARRAY()`

```
=MAKEARRAY(3,3,LAMBDA(a,b,a*b))*(MUNIT(3))
```

[image]